# pg_search with associated model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10543810/1197775).

I tried it:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :variants
  def skus; variants.map(&:sku).join(' ') end

  multisearchable :against => [:name, :slug, :skus]
end
```

but I am getting:

```
PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(Product)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column products.skus does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong? Could I take another alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I've bumped into this recently also. The `multisearch` reindex method assumes that all things that are `mutisearch`able against are database columns, and not methods.

There is an issue filed against this behavior here:
https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/issues/157

The simplest way to workaround this is to declare your `multisearchable` call with a proc that must be evaluated like so:

```
multisearchable :against => [:name, :slug, :skus],
                :if => proc{ true }
```

You can see how that changes the rebuild strategy [here](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/blob/v0.7.4/lib/pg_search/multisearch/rebuilder.rb#L16).

You could also redefine the `rebuild_pg_search_documents` method on your model as described in the README:

```
def self.rebuild_pg_search_documents
  find_each { |record| record.update_pg_search_document }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, skus needs to be scope, not a method.

I know this is short answer, but not enough reps to just add as a comment.

Comment: scope defines a class method, `against` receives column names which are instance methods, an option could be to cache skus in a new column, and updating them when variant changes. But scope is not an option from what I see.